# Deleting text content with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery function that can expand and collapse div content with <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> button.

[Here is an example on my website](http://www.izleveogren.com/1766-1-solidworkse-giris.html).

In my admin panel I write a link list before video embed code and php is using that link list to create part system.
My question is how can I change link list with jquery.
for example my link list is: ($text)

```
http://link1
http://link2
http://link3
http://link4
http://link5
*http://link6
http://link7
```

The link which contain * is the active part. Now 6. Bölüm (part 6) is active.
I just want to delete the links before link4. I said 4 because I want to put the * one in the middle.
That's hard but I don't know what can I do; can you just give me some advice?

And also here is my jquery code. You can use it if you want:

```
<script>     
$(function() {
    var cachedjQuery = $("#partsakla");
    var cachedEl = document.getElementById("partsakla");
    var cachedStyle = cachedEl.style;
    if ($("#partsaklasag").text().length > 1) {
        cachedStyle.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else{
        $("#partsakla").hide();
    }
    $("#collapse").click(function() {
        var elHeight = $("#partsakla").height();
        $("#partsakla").animate({ height: "22px" });
    });                
    var elHeight = $("#partsakla").height();
    $("#expand").click(function() {
        $("#partsakla").animate({ height: (elHeight) });
    });
    document.getElementById('collapse').click();                
});
</script>
```

I want to delete the link `list($text)` when the div is collapsed. And when someone clicks the expand button it change to normal. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do this...  var cachedEl = document.getElementById("partsakla"); when you can do this...  var cachedEl = $("#partsakla");

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work.

Comment: @GürselGünacar Your intent is not so clear... try to explain me... If I'm not wrong, you want that if you click on link 10, for example, on the top bar, near + and -  you see: **link 8 - link 9 - link 10 - link 11 - link 12**. That's right?

Comment: Yea @DavidC. i want that.Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your expand/collapse of the container (partsakla) works fine. You just need a way to select which links remain visible. So something like this:

```
function get_active_link() {
   return $('#partsaklasag ul li.active');
}

// numberToShow should be an odd number
// removes the links we want to keep from the list so they stay visible
function get_links_around($list, $link, numberToShow) {
   var before, after, start, end,
       total   = numberToShow,
       $before = $link.prevAll(), 
       $after  = $link.nextAll(),
       curr    = $before.length,
       half    = (numberToShow-1)/2;

   if( before < half ) {
      after = numberToShow-1-before;
   }
   else if( after < half ) {
      before = numberToShow-1-after;
   }
   else {
      before = half;
      after = half;
   }

   start = curr-before;
   end = curr+after;

   return $list.filter(function(i, v) {
      return i >= start && i <= end;
   });

}

function collapse() {
   var $list = $('#partsaklasag ul li').hide();
   get_links_around($list, get_active_link(), 5).show();
   $("#partsakla").animate({ height: "22px" });
}

function expand() {
   var $list = $('#partsaklasag ul li').show();
   $("#partsakla").animate({ height: (elHeight) });
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer Kato but i couldnt do that.My list is $text i changed $list to $text.And i want to show 5 parts.I didnt understand what am i have to do with numberToShow.I am new with jquery.Can u explain more pls

Comment: numberToShow, and the call to get_links_around, is in the collapse() function above. You would simply call collapse and expand in your click() functions. But honestly, this is a Q&A forum and not a tutorial site; you need to start with some tutorials and [a book on jQuery](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1935182323/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=wulf-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1935182323)...

Comment: I don't say that to be mean or make it sound like I'm above you--we all dive in head first in the beginning--but rather simply out of honesty; this is about as simple as jQuery code gets, which means you need to start with [a good solid overview](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials), then come back to this project :)

Comment: Thanks Kato for your advice.I will listen that ;)